# DIVs side by side (next to each other) in TopBar Navigation from SharePoint 2013 with CSS

Tags: css, sharepoint, html, css-float

I like to change a little bit the TopBar Navigation in SharePoint 2013. I like to have only one line instead of two lines...

What I like to do:

**1. I like to remove the green DIV that contains the links: Newsfeed, Skydrive, ... (suiteBarLeft)**

A: This I have done with `display: none;`

**2. I like to get the blue DIV "suiteBarRight" next to each other from the yellow DIV "s4-ribbonrow". The DIV "s4-ribbonrow" should be on the left side and the DIV "suiteBarRight" should be on the right side without any 'width' definitions...**

A: Every time I have the problem that the DIV "suitebarRight" is behind the DIV "s4-ribbonrow" but I can not work with 'margin or width' tags here...

Any idea how I could do this?

**See the following picture:**
[Picture](http://www.projects.harter-web.de/sharepoint/images/SharePoint2013_Ribbon.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself:

I had to use:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Thanks for your answer.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to provide you with a code solution without you providing us some base code to work with.  That said...

This should be approximately what you need to get started...

```
#suiteBar { float: left; }
#s4-ribbonrow { float: left; }
```